# set object value to another object in a JSON

Tags: json, object

I just wanted to know if I can do something like this in JSON:

```
{
    "web" : {
        "app_pub" : "localhost/public",
        "app_lib" : "localhost/lib",
        "app_assets" : "app_pub" + "/assets"
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a valid JSON. This is a valid JS object

Comment: @Weedoze so i can''t do something like this in json?

Comment: As I said, this is not a valid JSON. I think that you mix up JSON and JS objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check your JSON, using validator, i.e.:
https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Your code doesn't correspond RFC4627 and others.
You can't do operations inside JSON.

P.S.:
RFC4627 contains full JSON grammar.

Comment: ohh right . didn't thought about that . sorry and thank you :)